# Could abiogenesis still be ocurring?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, abiogenesis

From my understanding, most biologists believe that under certain conditions life can form from inert chemicals. If the conditions for this to happen still apply, is it possible that in bodies of water single-cell organisms could still be forming?

Comment: From the latest I've heard or read, there is too much oxygen in the atmosphere and oceans... Maybe highly anoxic places might suffice... Semi-arid areas on early land with small pools of water and underwater vents are where most scientists believe life arose... Way too much toxic/reactive O2 there now....

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please search the site before posting. Searching for "abiogenesis" shows several related questions, e.g. https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59892/is-abiogenesis-possible-today